# ASP.NET MVC5 REMOVE DATE FORMAT STRING

Tags: asp.net, date, asp.net-mvc-5, format

[image]

Im working with this view , so how can i remove this format dd/mm/yyyy and display nothing on it :

Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> PatientDOB_ { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PatientDOB_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientDOB_, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PatientDOB_, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: It must be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) in accordance with the specifications (and if the value is `null`, the datepicker will be empty)

Comment: i dont understand you sir , what to change ?

Comment: Seriously? you change `DataFormatString = ""` to `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"`!

Comment: sir , i changed to DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" , but dd/mm/yyyy still is there on texxtbox , and isnt disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are calling up the HTML5 date picker (which doesn't work on all browsers BTW).  I doubt there is a standard way of doing what you want via HTML5.  If you use one of the many datepickers from [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) or [bootstrap](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you might have more luck.

Comment: Hope you don't have any users with IE or Safari. https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime